# If $I$ is an nonzero ideal of $R_K$, Is $(R_K/I)^×$ finite abelian group in general?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$, and $R_K$ be ring of integers of $K$.
If $I$ is an nonzero ideal of $R_K$, Is $(R_K/I)^×$ finite abelian group in general ?

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Can you reduce to the case where $I$ is a power of a prime ideal, and then compare with the situation where $I$ is prime?

Comment: From Chinese reminder theorem, the problem reduces to examine $(R_K/p^e)^×$ , where $p$ is prime ideal. If this is in general finite abelian group, ① always holds.

Comment: Could you tell me why $R_K/I$ is finite and why $(R_K/I)^×$ is abelian group when $I$ is not $0$?

Comment: @The phoenix  The reason why $R_K/I$ is finite and it's unit group is abelian is not clear to me and that is exactly what I asked in this question. Could you give me more explanation ?

Comment: If $a\ne 0$ then the multiplication by $a$ (as a $\Bbb{Q}$-linear map $K\to K$) is invertible so $a O_K$ is a finite index sub-$\Bbb{Z}$ module of $O_K$ (this is linear algebra) and hence $O_K/(a)$ is a finite ring and $O_K/(a)^\times$ is a finite group. Choose $a\in I$ so $O_K/(a)^\times \to O_K/I^\times$ surjects and the latter is a finite group.

Comment: @reuns Is is abelian group?

Comment: $K$ and $O_K$ are commutative rings whence so is $O_K/I$ and its multiplicative group is abelian

Comment: If $a∈\Bbb{Z}$, order of $O_K/(a)$ is $a^2$ ?